# Twig - how to efficiently re-use code

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I have a page where I render details of many users. Each user's html is quite heavy (tooltips etc.) so I don't want to copy/paste the same code. I'd like to reuse the same code on different pages as well.

I was using **include** with parameters but I'm not sure how good the performance will be. Is it better to make a **Twig extension** and just have there functions producing html based on passed User instance? Or is there another, better approach?

**EDIT:**

This is the kind of code I'm rendering in multiple places on multiple pages.

```
<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="{{ user.getJob }}, {{ user.getCompanyy.getName }}">
    {{ user.getFirstName }}, {{ user.getLastName }}
</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [twig inheritance and symfony2 controller variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521477/twig-inheritance-and-symfony2-controller-variables)

Comment: Why not try both and do some benchmarks on both. I beleive this will differ case by case depending on what the includes contain/do. When you load the symfony page in app_dev it should tell you the time it takes to render the twig page and upon refreshing (after it has been cached) that number should come down. Does it seem excessive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include is a very good solution and fit exactly your needs.

You could use macros too ([documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)). But try to do not use `include` nor `require` in a macro because if you have an error in the included template, the line of the error will be the line where you called the template (not the one where you really have a bug) so it could become very difficult to debug.

And like you said, Twig extension could be good too for specifics cases. For instance, if you want to display a price, it's better to make your `|price` extension instead of include a little template. But extensions are better for highly reusable codes and shorts templates.

By the way, the worst case is using `render(controller(...))` only in order to display a template because it's very consuming in terms of memory.

Answer to Edit:

[Here you will find a benchmark](http://www.strangebuzz.com/post/2013/02/21/Twig-C-extension-benchmark): So extension seems to be the best solution in case of very lot of parameters. In your simple case, both solutions are good. Personnally, I prefer to use includes when I have lot of HTML and few parameters. But it's very a question of what you prefer.

You could even imagine doing both.

- include of the html widget
- and an extension in order to concatenate user firstname and lastname

Like this:

```
<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="{{ user.getJob }}, {{ user.getCompanyy.getName }}">
    {{ user|fullName }}
</span>
```

In conclusion, Twig provides lot of differents tools and it's up to you to choose the once that fits your needs.

Comment: I've edited my question. So am I right saying for this kind of code extension is best and for any larger code include makes more sense?

Comment: Thanks, this is a bit off topic now but how do I access escape filter from extension? I want to return non escaped html but parameters need to be escaped...

Comment: you can chain extensions calls. Like this myVariable|myOwnExtension|raw

Comment: yes but inside my php function (extension) where I take user instance I have to escape the company name before rendering it in the title attribute, is this possible?

Comment: Please create a new question and past here the link, I need more details in order to help you and we don't want to polute this topic.

Comment: You're right, also I'm starting to think macros is really what I need for this short html fragments. Thanks.

Comment: About `render(controller(...))` this is efficient with a cache correctly configured, and definitely useful if a view with its own context (such as a widget) is displayed several times in the app. Macros work well and are very good for common code (such as, displaying a photo+username attached to the logged-in user entity - exactly what fit your needs). Import a macro file in your base layout, and you'll get them available everywhere :-).

Comment: Thanks for all this clarifications. I agree `render(controller(...))` could be useful but, as I say, if it's used only for displaying a template: it's an overkill, so use with caution. About Macros, it's a very usefull tool but try to do not use `include` or `render` in a Macros, because errors are not logged to the included templates, errors stay in the maccros level: so it could becomehell in order to debug!