# Use Variables from Extended Template

Tags: php, twig

I have a question about how to use all variables from extended template.

I have these following PHP Functions as example:

```
function parent()
{
   $total_studies = Studies::where('studies', $studies)->count();

   echo $this->twig->render('/studies/parent.html.twig',
   [
      'number_studies' => $total_studies
   ]);
}


function child()
{
   $study_detail = Studies::where('studies', $studies)->first();

   echo $this->twig->render('/studies/child.html.twig',
   [
      'study' => $studies_detail
   ]);
}
```

in my `parent.html.twig` template, I have define

```
<h4> {{ number_studies }} </h4>
</ another html codes />
```

in my child `child.html.twig` template, I have used

```
{% use '/studies/parent.html.twig' %}
    {% block study_header %} {{ parent() }} {% endblock %}
<h4> {{ study.title }} </h4>
<h5> {{study.cover }} </h4> 
and so on..
```

Now the question is how my `child.html.twig` can also automatically displaying number of studies that is coming from `parent.html.twig` ? 
Maybe it because the {{ number_studies }} is defined inside function parent() and being rendered there ?

note: I know what AddGlobal is, but I do really want to render the variable and the twig html alone, and then inherit it into whatever that uses /studies/parent.html.twig'

Comment: Don't think u need to use `use`, have a look at [`include`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) instead

Comment: @DarkBee I have tried it just now,but no luck

Comment: @PramanaAdiPutra If you are rendering `child.html.twig`, you can't get a variable from `parent.html.twig`. That's because the value of `number_studies` is defined in the PHP method `parent()`, not in the Twig file.

Comment: @martias so how do I define it in the Twig file, so that it can inherit it values to children Twig templates?

Comment: @PramanaAdiPutra I don't know, but it sounds weird. Twig isn't a "data storage" or a "variable storage," it's a template engine. Or maybe I just don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @PramanaAdiPutra You said: "I know what AddGlobal is." Why not use that?

Comment: @martias it's similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521477/twig-inheritance-and-symfony2-controller-variables?rq=1 (its description)

That's kind of thing that I want to achieve, because 4 Twig Pages have something in common and that is display Course Details. But I do render the 4 Twig Pages in different controllers, and each controllers repeat the same code that takes Course Detail from Database. Thanks